# One Class Classification in R language. What am I doing wrong when generating the confusion matrix?

Tags: r, machine-learning, svm, supervised-learning, one-class-classification

I am trying to understand and implement classifiers A class in R is based on several UCIs and one of them (http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Chronic_Kidney_Disease).

When trying to print a confusion matrix you are giving the error “all arguments must have the same length”.

What am I doing wrong?

```r
library(caret)
library(dplyr)
library(e1071)
library(NLP)
library(tm)

ds = read.csv('kidney_disease.csv', 
              header = TRUE)

#Remover colunas inutiliz?veis              
ds <- subset(ds, select = -c(age), classification =='ckd' )

x <- subset(ds, select = -classification) #make x variables
y <- ds$classification #make y variable(dependent)

# test on the whole set
#pred <- predict(model, subset(ds, select=-classification))


trainPositive<-x
testnegative<-y

inTrain<-createDataPartition(1:nrow(trainPositive),p=0.6,list=FALSE)

trainpredictors<-trainPositive[inTrain,1:4]
trainLabels<-trainPositive[inTrain,6]

testPositive<-trainPositive[-inTrain,]
testPosNeg<-rbind(testPositive,testnegative)

testpredictors<-testPosNeg[,1:4]
testLabels<-testPosNeg[,6]

svm.model<-svm(trainpredictors,y=NULL,
               type='one-classification',
               nu=0.10,
               scale=TRUE,
               kernel="radial")

svm.predtrain<-predict(svm.model,trainpredictors)
svm.predtest<-predict(svm.model,testpredictors)

# confusionMatrixTable<-table(Predicted=svm.pred,Reference=testLabels)
# confusionMatrix(confusionMatrixTable,positive='TRUE')

confTrain <- table(Predicted=svm.predtrain,Reference=trainLabels)
confTest <- table(Predicted=svm.predtest,Reference=testLabels)

confusionMatrix(confTest,positive='TRUE')


print(confTrain)
print(confTest)

#grid
```

Here are some of the first lines of the dataset I'm using:

```
 id bp    sg al su    rbc       pc        pcc         ba bgr bu  sc sod pot hemo pcv   wc
1  0 80 1.020  1  0          normal notpresent notpresent 121 36 1.2  NA  NA 15.4  44 7800
2  1 50 1.020  4  0          normal notpresent notpresent  NA 18 0.8  NA  NA 11.3  38 6000
3  2 80 1.010  2  3 normal   normal notpresent notpresent 423 53 1.8  NA  NA  9.6  31 7500
4  3 70 1.005  4  0 normal abnormal    present notpresent 117 56 3.8 111 2.5 11.2  32 6700
5  4 80 1.010  2  0 normal   normal notpresent notpresent 106 26 1.4  NA  NA 11.6  35 7300
6  5 90 1.015  3  0                 notpresent notpresent  74 25 1.1 142 3.2 12.2  39 7800
   rc htn  dm cad appet  pe ane classification
1 5.2 yes yes  no  good  no  no            ckd
2      no  no  no  good  no  no            ckd
3      no yes  no  poor  no yes            ckd
4 3.9 yes  no  no  poor yes yes            ckd
5 4.6  no  no  no  good  no  no            ckd
6 4.4 yes yes  no  good yes  no            ckd
```

The error log:

```
> confTrain <- table (Predicted = svm.predtrain, Reference = trainLabels)
Table error (Predicted = svm.predtrain, Reference = trainLabels):
all arguments must be the same length
> confTest <- table (Predicted = svm.predtest, Reference = testLabels)
Table error (expected = svm.predtest, reference = testLabels):
all arguments must be the same length
>
> confusionMatrix (confTest, positive = 'TRUE')
ConfusionMatrix error (confTest, positive = "TRUE"):
'confTest' object not found
>
>
> print (confTrain)
Printing error (confTrain): object 'confTrain' not found
> print (confTest)
Printing error (confTest): object 'confTest' not found
```

Comment: Hi Stallone, welcome to Stack Overflow. I am unable to reproduce your code because 1) the link does not provide a `.csv` file but rather an `.arff` file and 2) you provide no detail on how you convert the `.arff` to `.csv`. It will be much easier to help if you provide a reproducible sample of the data. See [How to make a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) for more info.

Comment: Additionally, please provide *working code*. Above is at best starting from a single syntax error in your call to `read.csv`, but it's not always clear what problems in the code are due to your copy/paste error or because that's another problem with your code that you have yet to find or ask about. One benefit in how SO is showing R code above is that all code in red is considered to be part of a string. (The error is before that string starts, but it's still a clear indicator that something is amiss.)

Comment: A side note, that error usually means that you are feeding data sets with differing numbers of members you need to look the number of observations in both sets, if they are not the same then the matrix cannot compare them 1:1...my guess is somewhere up where you were making test sets you doubled something...

Comment: Hello @StaLLoNe_CoBRa, do you have GitHub? Could you create a repo and save the dataset there? I can help you but it's difficult to access the dataset you mention.

Comment: Hi @IanCampbell thanks for the feedback! I posted a head of the dataset I'm using!

Comment: Yes @sconfluentus! I already realized by what I searched on the internet when other people already had the same error! I just don't know where the part went ...

Comment: Hi @StaLLoNe_CoBRa, i suggest sorting your code out on what's label, what's train and test. if i run your code, this line ```testPosNeg<-rbind(testPositive,testnegative)``` gives an error, and it doesn't make sense at all

Comment: Hey @IanCampbell i puted the log error and part of dataset. Why still closed? Please help me!

Comment: It looks like most of us voted to close before your edit. I voted to reopen, and I will answer your question if it is re-opened.

Comment: @StupidWolf what error is showing to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a number of issues. First it seems that a lot of your data is of class character rather than numeric, which is required by the classifier. Let's pick some columns and convert to numeric. I will use `data.table` because `fread` is very convenient.

```
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(data.table)
setDT(ds)
#Choose columns
mycols <- c("id","bp","sg","al","su")
#Convert to numeric
ds[,(mycols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric),.SDcols = mycols]

#Convert classification to logical
data <- ds[,.(bp,sg,al,su,classification = ds$classification == "ckd")]
data
     bp    sg al su classification
  1: 80 1.020  1  0           TRUE
  2: 50 1.020  4  0           TRUE
  3: 80 1.010  2  3           TRUE
  4: 70 1.005  4  0           TRUE
  5: 80 1.010  2  0           TRUE
 ---                              
396: 80 1.020  0  0          FALSE
397: 70 1.025  0  0          FALSE
398: 80 1.020  0  0          FALSE
399: 60 1.025  0  0          FALSE
400: 80 1.025  0  0          FALSE
```

Once the data is cleaned up, you can sample a training and test set with `createDataPartition` as in your original code.

```
#Sample data for training and test set
inTrain<-createDataPartition(1:nrow(data),p=0.6,list=FALSE)
train<- data[inTrain,]
test <- data[-inTrain,]
```

Then we can create the model and make the predictions.

```
svm.model<-svm(classification ~ bp + sg + al + su, data = train,
               type='one-classification',
               nu=0.10,
               scale=TRUE,
               kernel="radial")

#Perform predictions 
svm.predtrain<-predict(svm.model,train)
svm.predtest<-predict(svm.model,test)
```

Your main issue with the cross table was that the model can only predict for cases that don't have any `NA`s, so you have to subset the classification levels to those with predictions. Then you can evaluate `confusionMatrix`:

```
confTrain <- table(Predicted=svm.predtrain,
                   Reference=train$classification[as.integer(names(svm.predtrain))])
confTest <- table(Predicted=svm.predtest,
                  Reference=test$classification[as.integer(names(svm.predtest))])

confusionMatrix(confTest,positive='TRUE')

Confusion Matrix and Statistics

         Reference
Predicted FALSE TRUE
    FALSE     0   17
    TRUE     55   64

               Accuracy : 0.4706         
                 95% CI : (0.3845, 0.558)
    No Information Rate : 0.5956         
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.9988         

                  Kappa : -0.2361        

 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.298e-05      

            Sensitivity : 0.7901         
            Specificity : 0.0000         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.5378         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.0000         
             Prevalence : 0.5956         
         Detection Rate : 0.4706         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.8750         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.3951         

       'Positive' Class : TRUE
```

**Data**

```
library(archive)
library(data.table)
tf1 <- tempfile(fileext = ".rar")
#Download data file
download.file("http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00336/Chronic_Kidney_Disease.rar", tf1)
tf2 <- tempfile()
#Un-rar file
archive_extract(tf1, tf2)
#Read in data
ds <- fread(paste0(tf2,"/Chronic_Kidney_Disease/chronic_kidney_disease.arff"), fill = TRUE, skip = "48")
#Remove erroneous last column
ds[,V26:= NULL]
#Set column names (from header)
setnames(ds,c("id","bp","sg","al","su","rbc","pc","pcc","ba","bgr","bu","sc","sod","pot","hemo","pcv","wc","rc","htn","dm","cad","appet","pe","ane","classification"))
#Replace "?" with NA
ds[ds == "?"] <- NA
```

Comment: Hey @Ian Campbell, first thanks for the help! But i tried to run your suggestions and one error was generated:  Error in `[.data.frame`(ds, , `:=`((mycols), lapply(.SD, as.numeric)),  : 
  unused argument (.SDcols = mycols)

Comment: Try `setDT(ds)` to convert to a `data.table` if it isn't already from the import.

Comment: Yeah! I got it! Thanks! But i don't understand why i can't run createDataPartition now? ```#Convert to numeric
setDT(ds)[, (mycols) := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = mycols]

#Convert classification to logical
data <- ds[,.(bp,sg,al,su,classification = ds$classification == "ckd")]

x <- subset(data, select = -classification) #make x variables
y <- data$classification #make y variable(dependent)

trainPositive<-x
testnegative<-y

inTrain<-createDataPartition(1:nrow(trainPositive),p=0.6,list=FALSE) ``` the output:``` could not find function "createDataPartition" ```

Comment: do null variables influence this?

Comment: Did you forget `library(caret)`?

Comment: No. I didn't forget. :/

Comment: Campbell, I saw that you already got the confusion matrix, but what was your parameter for trainpositive in createdatapartition?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, all of the code required is present in the answer. Perhaps try clearing all your RData and restarting R? `createDataPartition` is definitely in the `caret` package. Also, I don't understand why you are creating `x` and `y`. There is no need because you can specify them with the formula in `svm`.

Comment: Hey Campbell! Now I understand well what you did and the mistake I was making when trying to parameterize training and testing for ```svm```. As for the ```caret```, I was able to resolve it after reinstalling the package and restart R. Thank you very much, man!